# Ionic Framework hold click event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Is it possible to assign a button to a "hold click" event in TypeScript?

Like:

```
<button ion-button icon-only color="royal" (click)="addNote()" (holdclick)="removeNote()">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `press` event (more info in the [Gestures docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures)):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class BasicPage {

  public press: number = 0;

  constructor() {}

  pressEvent(e) {
    this.press++
  }

}
```

And in the view:

```
  <ion-card (press)="pressEvent($event)">
    <ion-item>
      Pressed: {{press}} times
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

If that's not enough (maybe you need a longer press event in your scenario), you can create your own gesture event by creating a custom directive. More information can be found in [this amazing article by roblouie](http://roblouie.com/article/198/using-gestures-in-the-ionic-2-beta/). The article uses an old version of Ionic, but the main idea is still the same (and pretty much all the code should work like it is):

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Gesture} from 'ionic-angular';

@Directive({
  selector: '[longPress]'
})
export class PressDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  el: HTMLElement;
  pressGesture: Gesture;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pressGesture = new Gesture(this.el, {
      recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Press, {time: 6000}] // Should be pressed for 6 seconds
      ]
    });
    this.pressGesture.listen();
    this.pressGesture.on('press', e => {
      // Here you could also emit a value and subscribe to it
      // in the component that hosts the element with the directive
      console.log('pressed!!');
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.pressGesture.destroy();
  }
}
```

And then use it in your html element:

```
<button longPress>...<button>
```

Comment: Genius. This makes the idea/functioning of the "Android Developer mode" with pressing the about button 10 times just seem so simple. Thanks.

Comment: Here's my full example. https://stephenmonro.wordpress.com/2019/10/29/secret-menu-in-an-ionic-app/